# php + mysql rows only returning int

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm starting out on php and I have the following script

```
<?php

$username = "firstleg_floa";
$password = "**";
$hostname = "***1";
$db = "firstleg_bank";
$guildUser = strtolower('grissiom');

$dbh = mysql_connect( $hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Unable To Connect");
$connectDB = mysql_select_db($db, $dbh);
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Bank where userId ='" .$guildUser."'");

$i = 0;
$rsArr = array();

While ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $rsArr [$i] [0] = $row{'userId'};
    $rsArr [$i] [1] = $row{'item'};
    $rsArr [$i] [2] = $row{'amount'};
    $rsArr [$i] [3] = $row{'position'};
    $i++;
}
?>
<?="ghdfdgdfg ". $rsArr[$i][1];}." ----";?>
    <? echo $rsArr[$i][0]; ?>
    <table>
    <tr><td>Item</td><td>Amount</td></tr>
    <?for ($x=0;$x <= $i; $x++)
    {?>
    <tr><td><?=$rsArr[$x][3];?></td><td><?=$rsArr[$x][2];?></td></tr>
    <?}?>
    </table>

<?php
mysql_close($dbh); ?>
```

and I have the following data in the database

1 - grissiom  - Silk Cloth -    100 -   1

with the above data and the above script all I can manage to pull out is the amount(100) and the position(1) how come i am unable to pull anything else out? can someone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after loop is finished $i is equal to 1, but $rsArr[$i] is not defined, so variables $rsArr[$i][0] and $rsArr[$i][1] doensn't exists, try using $rsArr[0][0] and $rsArr[0][1] like this:

```
<?="ghdfdgdfg ". $rsArr[0][1];}." ----";?>
    <? echo $rsArr[0][0]; ?>
    <table>
    <tr><td>Item</td><td>Amount</td></tr>
    <?for ($x=0;$x <= $i; $x++)
    {?>
    <tr><td><?=$rsArr[$x][3];?></td><td><?=$rsArr[$x][2];?></td></tr>
    <?}?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4):

It could be because you're using curly braces instead of square.  The row returned by `mysql_fetch_array()` is a PHP array, not an object or string.

Comment: arrays in php may also be defined with curly braces. this is not a problem.

Comment: Milen, try running this code:

<?php
$arr = array('test' => 'a test','another test2' => 'test',);
echo $arr['test']."\n";
$arr{'test3'} = 'third element';
var_export($arr);
echo "\n";

$arr2 = array('test1','test2','test3');
echo $arr{2}."\n";
array_push($arr2,'test4');
var_export($arr2);
?>

Comment: the only problem is that you can't define $arr{} = 'value'

Answer (score 3):

Possible solutions:

1) Those column names in the DB have different case, e.g. **userId** could be just **userid**

2) Those columns don't exist.

3) You are using curly braces, instead of square brackets:

```
 $rsArr [$i][0] = $row{'userId'}; //wrong
 $rsArr [$i] [0] = $row['userId']; //correct
```

Try replacing the while loop with this, it will read out the contents of each record as the DB has passed it to PHP:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<pre>' . var_dump($row) . </pre>;
}
```

to see exactly what is coming back from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

It seem ok to me, maybe issue is given from using curly braces.

Anyway i'd go with some simpler syntax, i.e:

```
<?php

$username = "firstleg_floa";
$password = "**";
$hostname = "***1";
$db = "firstleg_bank";
$guildUser = strtolower('grissiom');

$dbh = mysql_connect( $hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Unable To Connect");
$connectDB = mysql_select_db($db, $dbh);
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Bank where userId ='" .$guildUser."'");

$i = 0;
$rsArr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $rsArr[] = $row;
}
mysql_close($dbh);
echo '<table><tr><td>Item</td><td>Amount</td></tr>';
for ($i = 0;$i<count($rsArr);$i++){
    echo <<<EOF
    <tr><td>{$rsArr["item"]}</td><td>{$rsArr["amount"]}</td></tr>
EOF;
}
echo '</table>';
 ?>
```